Blazor Persist state to avoid double rendering is causing "server error"
I have the following code to populate a data grid:
@implements IDisposable
@inject IRecordServices RecordServices
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject IJSRuntime js
@inject Radzen.NotificationService NotificationService
@inject PersistentComponentState ApplicationState


@rendermode InteractiveServer

..............DataGrid populated with records...............


    IEnumerable<RecordEntity>? records;
    RadzenDataGrid<RecordEntity> grid = new RadzenDataGrid<RecordEntity>();
    PersistingComponentStateSubscription rendering = new PersistingComponentStateSubscription();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        rendering = ApplicationState.RegisterOnPersisting(() =>
        {
            ApplicationState.PersistAsJson(nameof(records), records);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        });

        if (!ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson(nameof(records), out IEnumerable<RecordEntity>? restored))
            records = await GetAllRecordsForGrid();
        else
            records = restored;
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<RecordEntity>> GetAllRecordsForGrid()
    {
        return await RecordServices.GetRecordEntities();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        rendering.Dispose();
    }

OnInitializedAsync() is supposed to run twice and it normally does, but when I try to add the RegisterOnPersisting(), the OnInitializedAsync() only runs once and then my web application is rendered but it gives a generic server error and the page is not interactable.
I really want to get this Persist State working so the component doesn't render twice.
What am I doing wrong?

after disabling the prerendering, whether it works well? If still not working, can you create a minimal sample to reproduce the problem?


OnInitializedAsync() is supposed to run twice and it normally does,
but when I try to add the RegisterOnPersisting(), the
OnInitializedAsync() only runs once and then my web application is
rendered but it gives a generic server error and the page is not
interactable.
I really want to get this Persist State working so the component
doesn't render twice.

For the "generic server error", you could check the GetAllRecordsForGrid method, is there any error when you get records?
About the OnInitializedAsync method runs twice, the issue relates the
Prerendering.
To disable the prerendering and make the OnInitializedAsync method run once, you can set the render mode as below:
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))

About using Persist prerendered state, I suggest you could check the following code:
@page "/prerendered-counter-2"
@implements IDisposable
@inject ILogger<PrerenderedCounter2> Logger
@inject PersistentComponentState ApplicationState
@rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false))
<PageTitle>Prerendered Counter 2</PageTitle>

<h1>Prerendered Counter 2</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount;
    private PersistingComponentStateSubscription persistingSubscription;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        persistingSubscription =
            ApplicationState.RegisterOnPersisting(PersistCount);

        if (!ApplicationState.TryTakeFromJson<int>(
            nameof(currentCount), out var restoredCount))
        {
            currentCount = Random.Shared.Next(100); //set initialized data.
            Logger.LogInformation("currentCount set to {Count}", currentCount);
        }
        else
        {
            currentCount = restoredCount!;
            Logger.LogInformation("currentCount restored to {Count}", currentCount);
        }
    }

    private Task PersistCount()
    {
        ApplicationState.PersistAsJson(nameof(currentCount), currentCount);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose() => persistingSubscription.Dispose();

    private void IncrementCount() => currentCount++;
}

More detail information, see Persist prerendered state.
